# utf8_unicode_ci String is inserted incorrectly?

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, jooq

I have java application through which I do different operations on MySQL DB. The probleam is that when inserting utf8 String it is not inserted correctly. The charset of DB is `utf8` and I have set collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`. Server connection collation is also `utf8_unicode_ci`. Furthermore when I insert data from *phpMyAdmin* it is inserted correctly, but when I do it from Java application using JOOQ - it is not. Example:

```
Result<ExecutorsRecord> executorsRecord =
                        context.insertInto(EXECUTORS, EXECUTORS.ID, EXECUTORS.NAME, EXECUTORS.SURNAME, EXECUTORS.REGION, EXECUTORS.PHONE, EXECUTORS.POINTS, EXECUTORS.E_TYPE)
                                .values(id, name, surname, region, phone, 0, type)
                                .returning(EXECUTORS.ID)
                                .fetch();
```

where `name = "Бобр"` and `surname = "Добр"`, produces tuple with ???? as a name and ???? as surname. I have checked both strings, they are passed correctly to the method correctly.

Comment: Stated here is the server connection collation... have you verified that the encoding is specified correctly on the JDBC connection from Java   e.g. `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`   (My suspicion is that the JDBC driver/connection is "helping" in a way that is not very helpful.)

Comment: @spencer7593 could you please link some documentation?

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using, MySQL Connector/J or the MariaDB Connector/J ? and what version ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html  and  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/

Comment: Also check the strings that you pass. Sometimes the unicode characters can be lost before the insert statement (for example if you pass the value between strings etc)

Comment: @spencer7593, thank you. I have added `?characterEncoding=utf8`, now it works. Consider writing an answer, i guess it might be helpful for someone.

Comment: My suggestion was just a guess. When we've got things configured correctly, and things aren't working, our goto suspect is the JDBC driver. To get timezone differences between the JVM and the MySQL database sorted out, to prevent the JDBC driver from "helping" by doing an illogical combination of various operations, we had to add two extra obscurely documented settings to the connection string. I suggest you write an answer to the question. I'm sure you are not the only one that has run into this issue.

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: @RickJames, thanks. Added a link to the answer as further reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @spencer7593 suggested the problem could be in JDBC connector. So I added into `url` of connection following: `?characterEncoding=utf8` so that final url was `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?characterEncoding=utf8"`, where `mydb` is a name of database. This has sorted out my problem. Also I would like to add the following statement (again by @spencer7593):

> When we've got things configured correctly, and things aren't working, our goto suspect is the JDBC driver. To get timezone differences between the JVM and the MySQL database sorted out, to prevent the JDBC driver from "helping" by doing an illogical combination of various operations, we had to add two extra obscurely documented settings to the connection string.

Further [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored/38363567#38363567)